Asymptotic: Issue with constant term of Asympotic of rational function
Here is a simple function to show the issue:
f[x_] := 3 x + 2 + 2/(x + 1)

It is very clear from this expression that the asymptote for f for x -> Infinity should be 3x + 2.
But to my suprise
Asymptotic[f[x], x -> Infinity]

yields

3x

I might be missing something about the Asymptotic function here, but it does not match with my understanding of the topic.
Further investigations:
If I define
g[x_] = f[x] // Together

we get one fraction
$$g(x)=\frac{4 + 5 x + 3 x^2}{1 + x}$$
And inverting the whole process via
Apart[g[x]]

yields the initial representation
$$ 2 + 3 x + \frac{2}{1 + x}$$
which is the expected result and shows that Mathematica extracts the polynomial 2 + 3 x as expected from the whole expression.
It is my understanding that the Asymptotic function uses the power series expansion, so if I set
psf[x_, y_] = Series[f[x], {x, y, 1}]

and then take a look at the limit y->Infinity
Limit[psf[x, y], y -> Infinity]

I get the expected result

2 + 3 x
which is not the result of Asymptotic, which just gives me 3 x


"it does not match with my understanding of the topic", so what is your understanding of the topic? I find the output of Asymptotic makes sense.

It gives leading asymptotic term. Limit[(3 x + 2 + 2/(x + 1))/(3 x), x -> \[Infinity]] == 1, the limit already approaches 1. No need to add 2 to have Limit[(3 x + 2 + 2/(x + 1))/(3 x + 2), x -> \[Infinity]] == 1.

Up to to documentation, Asymptotic uses Series. How about x*Series[(3 x + 2 + 2/(x + 1))/x, {x, Infinity, 1}] // Normal?

@yarchik Could you explain further why it makes sense to you? I would have expected 3x+2 instead of 3x as my understanding of an asymptote is Limit[f[x]-a[x], x->Infinity] to be zero, with a[x] being the asymptote. And if I interpret it as the leading asymptotic term, I would think of leading in terms of power series and that would yield 3x+2 (as shown in my post above). It's probably due to some definition I am not aware of, but what computation actually leads to 3x?

$f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are asymptotically equal as $x\rightarrow x_0$, i.e. $f\sim g$ when $f(x)=g(x)+o(g(x))$ as  $x\rightarrow x_0$. $h(x)$ is asymptotically smaller than $g(x)$ when forall ε>0, there exists δ>0 such that, for 0<|z−z0|<δ $|h(x)|\le \epsilon |g(x)|$. Now it is easy to show that $2=o(3x)$, thus $f\sim3x$.

@Wizard You are confusing two terms - Asymptote and Asymptotic analysis. Mathematica's Asymptotic does not compute asymptote it computes asymptotic behavior of a function, i.e. asymptotic analysis. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis.

@yarchik Thanks for the explanation, I was indeed not aware of the definition of asymptotic equality.

@azerbajdzan Yes, that was the case. Thanks for the explanation.

Here a way to get all successive asymptotes using Asymptotic
    asy[expr_, iter_ : 3] := 
 NestList[# + Asymptotic[expr - # , x -> Infinity] &, 
  Asymptotic[expr, x -> Infinity] , iter]

example
asy[3 x + 2 + 2/(x + 1), 2] (*{3 x, 2 + 3 x, 2 + 2/x + 3 x}*)


(+1) There is also Normal@Series[f[x], {x, ∞, #}] & /@ Range[-1, 3], which may be more easy to remember.

??? How it fails? It provides exactly the same result as yours.

I believe Asymptotic uses Series internally anyway. So if Series fails the Asymptotic would fail too.

Sorry for the delay, I was looking for an example(sorry for the longly expression) where Series and Asymptotic give different results: expr = 1/2 (-4 n + n^2 - n Log[4] + 4 n Log[n] -      2 n Log[n - n/(2 Log[n])] + (-1 + 2 n) Log[1 + n - 2 Log[n]] -      2 n Log[Log[n]] + (     n (1 + Log[4] +         Log[n - n/(2 Log[n])] - (1 + n) Log[1 + n - 2 Log[n]] +         2 Log[Log[n]]))/Log[n] -      Log[(\[Pi] (-1 + 2 Log[n]))/(2 Log[n]^2)])

??? Again. What different result? They are the same. Just use FullSimplify on your asy and compare with output of Series. They are same. You can hardly  find any counter example for analytical function. Only difference is that Asymptotic can work with some nonanalytical functions.

Mathematica v12.2 gives different results for expr=...!

So it is a failure of an old version. Maybe it is just that it is not able to simplify the output. Try to plot both result, they should match each other. Anyway, it is unimportant for OP questions so I am leaving the discussion.

@azerbajdzan Thanks for your reply. In MMA v12.2 the simple example expr=Gamma[x] gives two different results too. Which results finds MMA v14 in this case?

It gives E^-x Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] x^(-(1/2) + x) as first term in both cases (after simplification).

@azerbajdzan Thanks, then a lot has improved with the new version

Following the usual way of calculus, one obtains
 Asymptotic[f[x] - x*Asymptotic[f[x]/x, x -> Infinity], 
  x -> Infinity] + Asymptotic[f[x], x -> Infinity]


2 + 3 x

and/or
x*Series[(3 x + 2 + 2/(x + 1))/x, {x, Infinity, 1}] // Normal


2 + 3 x


@The down-voter: What is incorrect in my answer? It's unfair to down vote without any explaining comment.
